# Validity of VAR model based on cross-correlogram of residuals

Tags: vector-autoregression, cross-correlation

I have estimated a VAR model and plotted the correlograms and cross-correlogram of the residual series. The correlograms look OK: there is only one small significant correlation in each of them, but they can be validated using the Box-Ljung test.

However, in the cross-correlogram, there is a significant cross-correlation at lag zero (which is the only significant cross-correlation). Does this invalidates the estimated VAR model? Or does this mean the VAR is valid, but it doesn't allow to make any presumptions about the causal direction of the relationship between the series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with contemporaneous correlations in a reduced-form VAR model (in contrast to the Structural VAR model). This does not violate any assumptions about estimation or selection of VAR models.

You can investigate causality if you wish, e.g. Granger causality. Implicitly, there already is "instantaneous causality" due to the cross-correlations at zero lag.